# javascript not hiding form

Tags: javascript, php, hidden

The error messages on this form ('after') should be getting hidden by default and only showing when the user presses "Register" submit button. However all the error messages are being shown  by default - could any help suggest why this isnt working? The javascript file is printing to the console so it can find the file. Ive put the PHP for the form and the javascript below - any help would be very much appreciated, thank you,

This is the PHP to display the form:

```
<div class="span5 pull-right reg-form hidden">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Users.Register', array(
        'url' => '/register',
        'class' => 'span12 pull-right'));

    echo $this->Form->hidden('current_url', array('value' => $this->here));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Email:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-email-err show-err">This email address is already taken</span>
            <span class="hidden show-emailvalid-err show-err">This email is not valid</span>'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('confirm_username', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Confirm Email:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-user-err show-err">Re-email is incorrect</span>'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Password:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-pass-long show-err">Password must be at least 6 characters</span>'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'type' => 'password',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Confirm Password:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-pass-err show-err">Re-password is incorrect</span>'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Name:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-firstname-err show-err">This field must not empty</span>'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array(
        'class' => 'reg-input',
        'label' => array('text' => 'Last Name:', 'class' => 'reg-label main-color'),
        'div' => array('class' => 'span12 reg-div'),
        'required' => FALSE,
        'after' => '<span class="hidden show-lastname-err show-err">This field must not empty</span>'
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Register', 'div' => false, 'id' => 'RegSubmit', 'class' => 'btn-sign pull-right')); ?>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
(function($){
    /** $(document).ready(function(){}) */
    $(function(){ 
        console.log('cover');
   /*     
        $('#btn-reg').on('click', function(){
            $('#RegisterUsername').val($('#LoginUsername').val());
            $('.reg-form').removeClass('hidden');
        });
      */  
        $('#RegSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
            //console.log(e);
            if($('.show-user-err').attr('class').indexOf('hidden') < 0)
                $('.show-user-err').addClass('hidden');
            var username = $('#RegisterUsername').val(),
                re_username = $('#RegisterConfirmUsername').val(),
                password = $('#RegisterPassword').val(),
                re_password = $('#RegisterConfirmPassword').val(),
                firstname = $('#RegisterFirstname').val(),
                lastname = $('#RegisterLastname').val();

                var check = 0;
                var email_regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
            $.each(user_emails, function(index, value){
                if(value==username){
                    check = 1;
                }
            });
            if(check == 1){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-email-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(!email_regex.test(username) || username == '') {
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-emailvalid-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(username != re_username){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-user-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(password.length < 6){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-pass-long').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(password != re_password){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-pass-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(firstname == ''){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-firstname-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }
            if(lastname == ''){
                $('.show-err').addClass('hidden');
                $('.show-lastname-err').removeClass('hidden');
                return false;
            }

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that one of the other classes like show-err has display:block and that's overriding the hidden class. If you inspect the element in either Chrome or Firefox then it should show you the CSS rules that are being applied.

Comment: thanks - i added another CSS for hide "hidden" and this got it working. the javascript was fine all along